# Codeception Actor Actor vs Helper?

Tags: php, testing, codeception

In Codeception, the documentation suggests I add actions to `Helper\Acceptance` class which are then included in the `AcceptanceTester` class. The `AcceptanceTester` class also says this:

```
class AcceptanceTester extends \Codeception\Actor
{
    use _generated\AcceptanceTesterActions;

   /**
    * Define custom actions here
    */
}
```

So I can add my actions to the `AcceptanceTester` which is more straightforward for both a developer and his IDE than the auto-generated trait.

Is there any difference and why the documentation suggests the less straightforward way?

Answer (score 1):

I Just checked the documentation. So `Helper\Acceptance` class is act as `codeception` module. Because it's a module, defining some `public method`s to this class can be loaded/called in another module. See example [here](http://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers#accessing-other-modules). That's the difference with `AcceptanceTester` class, the `methods` will only accessible via `$I` instance. Honestly never try all of the implementation deeper. But this is a very good topic to discuss.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this. Documentation is a bit finicky so I had to put this together from multiple pages (references are included below).

#### Actors

> All actions and assertions are performed by the Actor object [source](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode)

Actor is actually used when you define your tests:

```php
public function loginAsRegularUser(\AcceptanceTester $I)
```

or

```php
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
```

Actor itself acts as a proxy for the modules (helpers):

> The FunctionalTester class has its methods defined in modules. Actually, it doesn’t contain any of them, but rather acts as a proxy. It knows which module executes this action and passes parameters into it. [source](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers.html)

To take advantage of IDE autocompletion, you may need to manually generate methods:

> To make your IDE see all of the FunctionalTester methods, you should run the `codecept build` command. It generates method signatures from enabled modules and saves them into a trait which is included in an actor. [source](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers.html)

Remember, that there can be only 1 actor per suite ([reference](https://codeception.com/docs/reference/Configuration.html)).

#### Helpers

Modules contain the actual actions and assertions:

> All actions and assertions that can be performed by the Tester object in a class are defined in modules. [source](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers.html)

> You can extend the testing suite with your own actions and assertions, by writing them into a custom module, called a Helper. [source](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode)

#### Conclusion

If you will further inspect `\Codeception\Module` and `\Codeception\Actor` you will realize that both serve *very different* purposes. Modules (or helpers) are meant to provide actions and assertions.

On the other hand, actor is a proxy between module and the tested code. Actor has access to `$scenario` where you can get meta information such as test description or its name.

Modules are able to interact with other modules ([source](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers.html#Accessing-Other-Modules)) and they have lifecycle hooks ([source](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers.html#Hooks)).

#### Bonus - StepObjects

> StepObjects are great if you need some common functionality for a group of tests. ([source](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#StepObjects))

StepObjects are extended from *actors* as they extend the actor of a given suite. Now it probably makes more sense why StepObjects are assigned to a specific suite instead of being a generic class:

> `php vendor/bin/codecept generate:stepobject acceptance Admin`

When to use StepObjects? When you want to group *actor-related actions* such as grouping together multiple asserts or multiple actions.

#### Bonus - PageObjects

> The PageObject pattern represents a web page as a class and the DOM elements on that page as its properties, and some basic interactions as its methods. ([source](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#PageObjects))

Selenium documentation contains further details - [link](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/guidelines_and_recommendations/page_object_models/).

If you are familiar with MVC, PageObject looks like a model of a tested page i.e. it contains actual css and xpath queries so that they don't pollute actual tests. Refer to Codeception manual for an actual example.

#### Bonus Conclusion

So when to use StepObjects as opposed to PageObjects? Here is the recommendation from Codeception:

> Group common [actor] actions together and move them to an Actor class or StepObjects. ([source](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#Conclusion))

> Move CSS and XPath locators into PageObjects. ([source](https://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#Conclusion))

To paraphrase this, your css and xpath queries should be moved to PageObjects while common actions and assertions should be moved to StepObject.

Comment: Thanks for putting this together. My mind spins at the documentation, I wish each section started with more simple declarative statements: PageObjects are X and you use them for Y. Rather than the roundabout mix of examples and asides that fill up these pages.